# Set VS DefaultLocation based on build configuration

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, configuration, installation

Any ideas on how to get the Default location of the Application Folder, to depend on the Build configuration? (Debug vs Release vs Release_Special)

so if it's on release it will default to c:\Program Files\MyApp and if its Release_Special it will be C:\MyApp\

Appreciate the help!

Comment: sorry, I missed the installer tag.  :)  What installer are you using?  Is this a ClickOnce deployment sort of thing?

Comment: Hi Dave, actually installer might be a insy bit misleading.. This is a .vdproj and that comes three default folders: "Application Folder", "User's Desktop", "User's Programs Menu" - of these three im only concerned with the first one and it's location...  (Hope that makes more sense! :S)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for reference, the way to do this turned out to be creating a standard installer and then solving the default install paths by using a batch script and passing through to setup.exe the TARGETDIR param.

```
setup.exe TARGETDIR="C:\App"
```

Thanks all for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're asking two questions:

1. How do I set the Application folder?  I know you said "get", but as far as I know, the application folder doesn't change unless you specifically try to do it yourself, and I think the only way to do that is to go outside of what Environment gives you.  I think you'll have to manage this information yourself.
2. How do I get different behavior based on a build configuration?  You can go with the standard #ifdef preprocessor macro, but the proper way to do it in .NET is to use the ConditionalAttribute: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There's a setting for that on the *Project properties* page.
Look at the *Output path* property on the *Build* tab.
Unfortunately, you have to do it for every single project in your solution.

HTH.
Thomas

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks for the answer. Im familiar with the Output path, but unfortunately thats not quite what I'm looking for. I want to be able to change the default location that the installer suggests when a user runs the setup.exe (not where the projects are built).